# Change subject of this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I change the subject of the equation below to $b$?

$$a = \frac{k}{2b + 4c}$$

I'm getting nowhere with this one.

Comment: Welcome to the Math StackExchange.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rearrange in a few steps:
$$2ab+4ac=k$$ $$2ab=k-4ac$$ $$b=\frac{k-4ac}{2a}$$